# Clicking on POST link on page desn't not calling the onchange ajax event to save the modified field

Tags: ajax

Saving a field on change ajax to server works when click outside the box but doesn't change the value if click on any POST link on the page immediately after changing the value.

Below is the code html:

```
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" size="40" value="${fieldValue}" onchange="doAJAXSubmit(this.name, this.value)"/>
```

JS:

```
function doAJAXSubmit(fieldSaved, fieldValue)
{
    alert(fieldSaved);
    var url = "<c:url value="/home/home.jsp"/>";

    url = url+fieldSaved+ "=" + fieldValue;
    new Request({url: url}).send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the document.ready .change binding from jquery

```
$('#title').change(function() {
    alert(fieldSaved);
    var url = "<c:url value="/cart/view_cart.jspa"/>";

    url = url+fieldSaved+ "=" + fieldValue;
    new Request({url: url}).send();
});
```

Without Jquery do the following:
Then change your code to the following:

using onkeyup

```
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" size="40" value="${fieldValue}" onkeyup="doAJAXSubmit(this.name, this.value)"/>
```